# Is double layer model possible in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

Here is a list of products ordered by color :

RED

Product red 1 Product red 2 Product red3

BLUE

Product blue 1

YELLOW

Product Yellow 1

To do that I have to differentiate the products in the controller :

```
@productscolor={}
@products.each do |product|
   @productscolor=[product.color][product]
end
```

But in the view, how do i manage it?

i will have a _colorproduct.erb and a _colorproductdetail.erb i guess.

What is the name of this kind of double loop view? Is it doable in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you need is the group by enumeration

```
@productscolor = @products.group_by{|x|x.color}
```

This means your @productscolor instance variable now has

```
{"Yellow" => [Product1, Product2], "Red" => [Product3, Product4], ...}
```

You can sort over the keys of this hash of arrays and get color and then render partial collection on the products. In the view -

```
<% @productscolor.keys.sort.each do |color| %>
   <%= color %>
   <%= render :partial => 'colorproductdetail', :collection => @productscolor[color] %>
<% end %>
```

Modify at leisure.

Answer (score 1):

The short name is "broken", because you keep reassigning @productscolor ;)

You need a hash with the color as key and a list of products of that color as the value.

```
m = Hash.new([])
@products.each do |p|
    m[p.color] << p
end
```

Then use a collection partial for each color's products.